# AccessControl только для описанных actions

Tags: yii2

Как написать правило для ограничения доступа только к описанным actions. Как пример есть контроллер у которого есть 100 actions, и только 10 из них разрешено админам, все остальные разрешены для обычных пользователей.
Как **правильно** написать правило для этих действий?

Я это вижу как-то так (чтоб не дублировать два раза список, можно оформить в виде функции которая сгенерирует их автоматически)

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                #region Custom Actions
                //Запретить всем удалять
                [
                    'actions' => [
                        'delete',
                    ],
                    'allow' => false,
                ],
                //Разрешить админам удалять
                [
                    'actions' => [
                        'delete',
                    ],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => [User::ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR],
                ],
                #endregion

                #region Default Actions
                //Разрешить для всех пользователей все остальные actions
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                #endregion
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Или это делается иначе?